# Using awk to count how many time each species id occurs in multi fasta files

Tags: unix, awk, count, fasta

I searched this topic and could not find. I have 5593 multi fasta files and I need to count how many time each species id occurs in each file.
I can only identify the the total number of sequences in each species, but i can't identify the input files.

Input

file1.fasta:

```
>hsa
ATCGATCGATCAGACTACG

>eco
ATCGATCGATCAGACTACG
```

file2.fasta:

```
>hsa
GATCGATCAGACTACGAAA

>hsa
GATCGATCACAGACTACGAAA
```

file3.fasta:

```
>hsa
CTAGACTAGATAGACACATAGAGA

>ecj
CTAGACTAGCTAGACCCATAGAGA

>mmu
CTAGACAAGATAGACACAAAGAGA

>eco
CTAGACTACATCGACACATAGAGA
```

Expected output

```
file1.fasta >hsa [count]
file1.fasta >eco [count]
file2.fasta >hsa [count]
file3.fasta >hsa [count]

file3.fasta >ecj [count]
file3.fasta >mmu [count]
file3.fasta >eco [count]
```

<!-

```
awk /^>.../ {print $1} *.* | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Ouput

```
[total counts]>hsa

[total counts]>eco

[total counts]>mmu

[total counts]>ecj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 'species' lines start with `>`, and that the square bracketed expressions in the sample output are simple numbers, then:

```
awk 'BEGIN { SUBSEP = " " }
     /^>/ { per_file[FILENAME,$1]++; total[$1]++ }
     END { for (k in per_file) print k, per_file[k]
           for (k in total)    print total[k], k
         }' *.fasta
```

You'll probably need to do some sorting somewhere along the line, either in `awk` or afterwards, as there's no guarantee that the data presented by a `for (index in array)` loop will be in any particular order.

Without the `BEGIN` block (or other mechanism) setting `SUBSEP`, there would be a `\034` character after the filename and before the species key.  By setting `SUBSEP` to a blank, the filename is separated from the species key by a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `awk`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { SUBSEP = FS }
!(FILENAME in name) { fileorder[++num]=FILENAME; name[FILENAME]++ }
/^>/ { count[FILENAME,$1]++ }
END { 
  for (order=1; order<=num; order++) {
      for (total in count) {
          split(total, keys, SUBSEP)
          if (fileorder[order]==keys[1]) {
              print fileorder[order], keys[2], count[fileorder[order],keys[2]]
          }
      }
  }
}' file1 file2 file3
```

**Output:**

```
file1 >eco 1
file1 >hsa 1
file2 >hsa 2
file3 >eco 1
file3 >mmu 1
file3 >hsa 1
file3 >ecj 1
```

- In the `BEGIN` block we set `SUBSEP` to `FS`. This allows the composite keys to be separated by a space.
- We maintain two arrays, `name` and `fileorder`. If our file is not present in `name` array we populate the `fileorder` array with the filename.
- For the lines starting with fasta pattern we populate another array called `count` which has the filename and pattern as composite key and counts as value.
- In the `END` block, we iterate through our `fileorder` array and then our `count` array. We split the composite key using `split` function and check if filename is matching first part of our key. If it is we print the filename, pattern and count and move on to the next iteration.